# USB audio input have many noises in my arm device?

Tags: linux, audio

I have a linux-based embedded device which has a capture usb device. It connect Mac with usb line. I run arecord in my device, and then press play button in itunes. Thus I will get a wav file in my device.

My question is:
Usually the wave file I was listened is fine. But if I run a shell bash in the background before I run arecord，then the wave file has many noises.
The shell bash:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    if [ -d "/etc" ];then          
        x=1
    fi
    usleep 100000
done
```

I cut the wav's header and silence from the noise file and normal file. The compared result :
[The compared wav files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHL4m.png)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then don't do that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have a similar shell which must running background from start. When I running this shell, I will heard noises. It will be fine util the shell is killed.